# Does sklearn's LinearRegression use SVD?

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, regression, linear-regression

I can't find implementation details of sklearn's `LinearRegression` implementation. In https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html, section 1.1.1.2.  seems to imply that it uses SVD. I think most implementations I've seen uses QR factorization.
Does anyone know why sklearn uses SVD instead (assuming that is indeed what it uses)?

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-learn's `LinearRegression` uses different algorithms to fit the regression model:

- `scipy.linalg.lstsq` in the dense case with `positive=False`
- `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` in the sparse case with `positive=False`
- `scipy.optimize.nnls` when `positive=True`

---

See the scipy documentation for more details on these algorithms:

- [`scipy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html) uses by default a LAPACK solver called [`gelsd`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/lapack-routines/lapack-least-squares-and-eigenvalue-problem-routines/lapack-least-squares-and-eigenvalue-problem-driver-routines/linear-least-squares-lls-problems-lapack-driver-routines/gelsd.html)

  > ?gelsd. Computes the minimum-norm solution to a linear least squares problem **using the singular value decomposition** of A and a divide and conquer method.
- [`scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html) uses "an iterative method to approximate the solution"
- [`scipy.optimize.nnls`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) uses "a FORTRAN solver" based on "an active set method"

---

Concerning scipy's choice to use `gelsd` by default in `scipy.linalg.lstsq`, see for example [this thread](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3004).

Comment: I'm new to scikit-learn, but how is scipy related to this?